# Cannot assign value of type NSDictionary to a value of type NSDictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization, swift2

Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7 Beta 3), as far as I can tell the syntax looks great.  I obtain a JSON string earlier, then when I try to parse it, I get the above error on the "try NSJSONSerialization" line, on the "as" keyword.  What did I do wrong?  Thanks for your answers.

```
        var weatherData: NSDictionary
        do {
            weatherData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        } catch {
            // Display an error to user
            let errorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Unable to get weather data", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.presentViewController(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
```

Comment: Does weatherData have to be an NSDictionary, and not just a Swift-style dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the cast as `NSDictionary` with `!` (but it's better to use "guard" like in @robertvojta's answer).

Also, you can use `[]` instead of `MutableContainers`:

```
weatherData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary
```

[image: Playground screenshot]

*EDIT: Following @robertvojta's answer and explanations, I've edited out my wrong assertions about Swift 2 and force casting within "do ... catch". Also, note that in the screenshot NSData was only here for quick testing in the Playground, of course.*

Comment: So sorry, I thought I had posted that version of the code.  I tried with as!, that does not remove the compiler error.  I then tried removing it, must have pasted that into my question above.  I edited my original question, but the error still persists.

Comment: No problem, it happens. :) BUT it was indeed the error, see this [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFljRZRXKGpGs6qbUXkajOHfgQ1wnWsq1HM) of my Playground. If it still fails for you, it means there's a problem somewhere else than this snippet of code.

Comment: OK, first of all thanks a TON for posting that pic of your code.  It is much simpler than what I was trying (I had been hacking at it for hours, so it ended up becoming complex), and the simple version works.

Answer (score 2):

What @EricD wrote in his answer is wrong. Quote:

> With Swift 1.2 using ! was dangerous and it was better to use Optional
>   binding (if let ...) but in Swift 2 when you handle the errors with do
>   catch, you can actually use ! (but one should not forget to use a
>   generic catch, like you do, in addition to possible other specific
>   error handling).

`do catch` handles only and only (re)throwed errors. Nothing else. If you force unwrap optional which is `nil`, you're going to receive `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. And you'll get it even if your code is wrapped in `do catch`. Keywords like `throws`, `catch` can evoke that it's about exceptions, but it's not - just errors. Same applies to `as!`.

Rewrite it to something like this:

```
enum MyError: ErrorType {
  case ParsingFailed
}

// some jsonData you did receive
var jsonData: NSData?

do {
  guard let data = jsonData,
    weatherData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else {
      throw MyError.ParsingFailed
  }

  // here you can work with your weatherData dictionary in a safe way
  // it's NSDictionary and not an optional
}
catch {
  // Display an error to user
}
```

What it does:

- `jsonData` contains (or not) `NSData` you did receive in a response,
- `guard let data = jsonData` tries to get value from optional and if it succeeds, unwrapped value is stored in `data`, otherwise `MyError.ParsingFailed` is thrown,
- `weatherData = ...` is executed only and only if the previous `guard` statement succeeds,

  - it tries to create JSON object from data, if failed, error is thrown,
  - if it succeeds, it tries to cast it to `NSDictionary` (`as?`) and if this succeeds as well, `weatherData` contains your `NSDictionary` otherwise `MyError.ParsingFailed` is thrown

This is safe, it can't crash and all errors are handled in one place.

So, **don't use** what @EricD wrote. Using `as!` and `!` **is still dangerous** even in **Swift 2**.

`NSData(contentsOfURL:options:)` is not good idea as well. This is synchronous call, so, it is going to block your main thread (app looks like frozen) until the request fails or succeeds.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, I was sure to have tried before but... sigh. I've edited out this part of my answer. Thank you, a lot, for this update.

Comment: Ok I get the impression this is a more complete and better answer. But how do I go about becoming proficient in understanding optionals and error handling in Swift? The Apple book only gives so much reading and not as much depth of understanding. I've been googling those topics with some dim lightbulb going on.

Comment: [David Owens](http://owensd.io/posts/) - start with a blog post from Jun 09, several of them about error handling till today. [Airspeed Velocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net) blog. [Swift Blog by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/). Twitter, ... And mainly - read, try, fix, read, try, fix, ...

Comment: OK, that guard statement is very cool.  However, I can't find it in the Swift 2 documentation in Xcode, nor in the Swift 2 Programming Guide in iBooks.  Where did you find the documentation of that syntax?

Comment: Apple's The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2). Chapter Control Flow - Early Exit.